# Working around unexpected behavior in yaml for Ruby -- interned unicode strings

Tags: ruby, serialization, yaml, symbols

(1.9 on Windows)

Reproducing:

```
require 'yaml'

s = YAML::load("\xEC\x86\x8C\xEB\x85\x80\xEC\x8B\x9C\xEB\x8C\x80")
   # => "∞åîδàÇ∞ï£δîÇ" or "소녀시대", depending on your terminal's unicode support
s_interned = s.intern

s_interned.class    # => Symbol

s_yamld = s_interned.to_yaml
   # => "--- \":\\xEC\\x86\\x8C\\xEB\\x85\\x80\\xEC\\x8B\\x9C\\xEB\\x8C\\x80\"\n"
unyamld = YAML::load(s_yamld)
   # => ":∞åîδàÇ∞ï£δîÇ" or ":소녀시대"

unyamld.class       # => String
                    # => expected: Symbol
```

And once again:

```
YAML::load(s_interned.to_yaml).class   # => String
```

Here's how a "normal" symbol behaves:

```
YAML::load(:foo.to_yaml).class         # => Symbol
```

Normal symbols behave fine, but symbols with unicode characters don't seem to.  They get interpreted as strings with a colon as their first character.

I'm pretty sure this script was working last night.  But I woke up this morning and everything is gone wrong.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this or get around this?

I've tried using some clever regular expression/sub hacks to get around this and "reconvert", but they've all proven inelegant or have made the situation worse.

Comment: What is your file enconding? What is your default external encoding? Since you're using Ruby 1.9 (presume 1.9.2) you can check the encoding with .encoding.

Comment: @Luis I'm brand new to 1.9, so encoding stuff is pretty foreign to me.  `s` is UTF-8; `s_yamld` is ASCII-8BIT. `unyamld` is UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to 1.9 as well but it seems you have to add the encoding to the top of the file sometimes. Something like:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Again... no idea when or why. Still have to learn how it works in 1.9. I found some more background information here: "[Ruby 1.9 Common Problems Pt. 1: Encoding](http://gnuu.org/2009/02/02/ruby-19-common-problems-pt-1-encoding/)".

Comment: Does adding that commented line really work?  Does the compiler actually parse it?

Comment: I added a link to a blog post concerning this. So yes, it seems the compiler understands that. Don't know if it will solve your problem though.